# Why is neutral sigma baryon more massive than lambda baryon?

Tags: standard-model, isospin-symmetry, baryons

Neutral sigma-star baryon, neutral [sigma baryon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_baryon) and [lambda baryon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_baryon) have masses 1387 MeV, 1192 MeV, 1116 MeV respectively, whereas each of these 3 particles are composed of 1 up, 1 down and 1 strange quark. Neutral sigma-star baryon (spin 3/2) is more massive than neutral sigma baryon (spin 1/2) because of hyperfine splitting but why neutral sigma baryon is more massive than lambda baryon, which is also spin 1/2 particle like neutral sigma baryon?

Answer (score 2):

If one considers the [baryon octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_%28physics%29)

[image: baryonoctet]

the lambda 0 is a singlet  in isospin and the sigma zero is in a triplet.

The [explanation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/sigma.html) of the mass difference

> The neutral sigma can decay to the lambda without violating conservation of strangeness, so it proceeds rapidly by the electromagnetic interaction. The sigma-zero and lambda-zero have the same quark constituents so the sigma-zero can be considered to be an electromagnetic excited state of the lambda-zero

Also there exists the [Gell Mann- Okubo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann%E2%80%93Okubo_mass_formula) phenomenological formula which gives the mass according to the isospin.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [De Rujula, Georgi, and Glashow](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.12.147), two spin-1/2 particles in an S-wave bound state have a higher energy when their spins are parallel than when they are anti-parallel.  Colour magnetic interactions make the $\Sigma^0$ more massive than the $\Lambda$ because the $u$ and $d$ quark spins are parallel in the $\Sigma^0$ and anti-parallel in the $\Lambda$.

The spin-spin interactions between two quarks of $m$ and $S$ cause an energy shift

$$\Delta E \propto \frac{S_1 \cdot S_2}{m_1m_2} $$

For spin-1/2 fermions, $S_i \cdot S_j = +1/4$ for parallel spins and $-3/4$ for anti-parallel spins. According to De Rujula, Georgi, and Glashow,

$$M_\Sigma^0-M_\Lambda \propto \frac{1}{m_u}\left(\frac{1}{m_u}-\frac{1}{m_s}\right)$$

Since the strange ($s$) quark is heavier than the up ($u$) quark, the $\Sigma^0$ is more massive than the $\Lambda$.